# Assign Lookup Field via Lookup Value in Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, list-workflow

I need to assign a Lookup Field in List A to an item from List B. In List A my items contain a Link with description, wich contains the Title i need to look up in List B. So my Workflow on List A should look like this:

1. Get Link description from current Item and store it in a variable.
2. Perform some textfunctions to get the correct string to lookup in List B.
3. Assign this string to the Lookup Field in current Item.

Step 1 and Step 2 are already working, but i can't get Step 3 to work. Unfortunately i can't give you the exact Error because it is in German, but it says something like "Can't convert the typed in Lookupdata in requested type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to get the ID of the extracted title from the lookup list and set your lookup field with this ID :

1. in the SharePoint designer workflow, in the WORKFLOW ribbon, click **Local Variables**.
2. create & set a **string** local variable with the extracted title
3. create a new Local variable as **integer**.
4. set the integer variable with the **ID** of the lookup list item (from the lookup list)  using the extracted title variable.

[image]

5. Set List A's lookup value with the Integer local variable.
6. Save , Publish and test.

[image]

Comment: Sorry it seems like my description was not on point. An Item in List A has a Hyperlink Field and a Lookup Field. The Hyperlink description looks like this `M-XXXXX` where X is a Number 0-9 and the Link points to a website. I need to extract this 5 digit sequence out of that hyperlinkdescription wich works fine. But now i need to Look Up the Sequence in List B. But keep in mind that this 5 digit sequence is not the item-ID of an item in List B. It actually is the Title.

Comment: @Jul i updated my answer , please try and let me know

Comment: @Jul most welcome